# MySQL - Subquery in SELECT raising "unkown colum" on outer reference

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to get a field which is calculated by a subquery. I found about 400 posts at SO that state that you can use the outer ID in a select subquery clause unless you are trying to use it in a join (what I don't).

Here's my query:

```
SELECT (SELECT group_concat(ct.NAME) 
        FROM core_tagobject cto 
        JOIN core_tag ct ON ct.id=cto.tag_id 
         AND cto.context="tags_working_on" 
         AND cto.object_id=u.id) AS "tag_list"
FROM auth_user u
```

I always get back `SQL error (1054) - unknown column 'u.id' in 'on clause'.`

What am I doing wrong?

Thx!

Comment: Yes, your are using u.id in the on clause.

Comment: What should the `u.id` refer to ?  Does the table `auth_user` have and `id` ?  Please add the DDL for creating this table.

Comment: ';(what I don't do).' yes you do do..

Comment: Perhaps move the cto.object_id=u.id condition into the wehere clause of the subquery

Comment: The u.id comes/should come from the outer query. I want to have this field per user (outer query)

Comment: Move the condition `cto.object_id=u.id` from ON to WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want below sql

```sql
SELECT group_concat(ct.NAME) AS `tag_list`
FROM core_tagobject cto JOIN core_tag ct ON ct.id=cto.tag_id 
  JOIN auth_user u ON cto.object_id=u.id
WHERE cto.context="tags_working_on"
```

Comment: thx for your reply! but where is the external reference?

Answer (score 0):

With some data examples would be better to produce a proper solution, but could you try:

```
SELECT tag_list.*
FROM  auth_user u 
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT group_concat(ct.NAME) 
            FROM core_tagobject cto 
            JOIN core_tag ct ON ct.id=cto.tag_id 
            AND cto.context="tags_working_on" 
           ) AS tag_list on tag_list.object_id=u.id ;
```

Comment: i need to avoid joins because i have to get this table three times so my data will duplicate itself...

Comment: Basically it is the same as the question query. Without data examples I can't help you more